# ImageIO.read使用時のKeyListener<Java>

Tags: java, swing

`JPanel`を継承したクラスに`KeyListener`をつけているのですが、下のコードだと"入力"と表示されません。
コンストラクタ内にある`mapImg[n] = ImageIO.read(以下省略)`をコードから削除するとキー入力が反応するようになります。

この事象の発生理由と解決方法をご教授いただけないかと質問させていただきました。
どうぞよろしくお願いします。

```
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyListener;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;

import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class WindowPanel extends JPanel implements KeyListener {

    public static BufferedImage[] mapImg = new BufferedImage[3];
    public static String path = new File(".").getAbsoluteFile().getParent();


    public WindowPanel() {
        setFocusable(true);
        addKeyListener(this);

        try {

            mapImg[0] = ImageIO.read(new File(path)).getSubimage(0, 0, 20, 20);
            mapImg[1] = ImageIO.read(new File(path)).getSubimage(20, 0, 20, 20);
            mapImg[2] = ImageIO.read(new File(path)).getSubimage(40, 0, 20, 20);

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            System.out.println("エラー");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void paint(Graphics g) {
        super.paint(g);
        Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;
    }

    @Override
    public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {
        System.out.println("入力");
    }

    @Override
    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
        System.out.println("入力");
    }

    @Override
    public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
        System.out.println("入力");
    }
}
```

Comment: 実行している環境をご提示いただけると回答がつきやすいかと思います。私の環境、Mac OSX 10.11.2、Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_60-b27)では問題なく動作するようです。

Comment: `ImageIO.read(...)`で画像ファイルではなくディレクトリを読み込んでいるので`IIOException`はでますが、パネルを`JFrame`に追加すれば、自分の環境(`Windows 10 64bit` + `Java1.8.0_66`)でも`KeyListener`は正常に動作しています。